# TMediaPlayer and TMediaPlayerControl don't seem to work for Delphi FireMonkey iOS/Android?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

I have a Delphi XE6 FireMonkey project, intending to play videos on iOS and Android devices.

In my form I have TMediaPlayerControl and TMediaPlayer controls.

My code to play the video (passed in) is

```
MediaPlayer1.FileName := TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + s;
Label1.Text := IntToStr(MediaPlayer1.Media.VideoSize.Truncate.X) + 'x' +
    IntToStr(MediaPlayer1.Media.VideoSize.Truncate.Y) +
    'px ' + IntToStr(MediaPlayer1.Media.Duration div MediaTimeScale) + 'ms';
TrackBar1.Max := MediaPlayer1.Media.Duration;

MediaPlayer1.Play;
```

The intention is that a label will show the resolution of the video and the trackbar will show the length of the video.

Yet, the Label shows as 0x0 and the trackbar has value 0.

Now, if I set the MediaPlayer property of the TMediaPlayerControl, ie

```
MediaPlayerControl1.MediaPlayer := MediaPlayer1;
```

the video does not play at all. Nothing happens. If I clear that property, then the video does play but only in an uncontrolled window in the middle of the screen, ignoring the TMediaPlayerControl entirely.

This code works with a FireMonkey Windows app but it seems it does not work for iOS or Android.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or is this just broken? In which case how do you play videos in FireMonkey for iOS/Android?

Thank you!

Comment: The included VideoPlayback sample (installed by default in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Mobile Snippets\VideoPlayback) works for me in Android if you follow the instructions in the comments. Does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks Ken, I hadn't seen that sample before. However, interestingly, it does not use the TMediaPlayerControl component at all, just TMediaPlayer, and sure enough - like I'm experiencing - it plays as an uncontrollable window in the middle of the screen - without regard to the window borders, etc.

Comment: @DavidMWilliams I'm having similar issue while getting the Duration of the video. It's always return 0 on IOS or ANDROID, but it's work in Win32 application. Any news for solution or work around? Thanks

Comment: @thanh Sadly no solution. My workaround was to forget about Delphi and use Xamarin instead, sadly.